# LWJGL Shader not displaying anything to the screen

Tags: opengl, java, lwjgl

My basic shader program isn't displaying anything to the screen. Please Help!

Here's my code:

```
import org.hootengine.core.Game;
import org.hootengine.scene.Scene;
import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;

import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30.glBindVertexArray;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30.glGenVertexArrays;

public class DemoScene extends Scene {

    /*
     * Variables
     */
    private String vertexShaderSrc = "#version 330 core\n" +
            "layout (location=0) in vec3 aPos;\n" +
            "layout (location=1) in vec4 aColor;\n" +
            "\n" +
            "out vec4 fColor;\n" +
            "\n" +
            "void main()\n" +
            "{\n" +
            "    fColor = aColor;\n" +
            "    gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);\n" +
            "}";
    private String fragmentShaderSrc = "#version 330 core\n" +
            "\n" +
            "in vec4 fColor;\n" +
            "\n" +
            "out vec4 color;\n" +
            "\n" +
            "void main()\n" +
            "{\n" +
            "    color = fColor;\n" +
            "}";
    private int vertexId, fragmentId, shaderProgram;

    private float[] vertexArray = {
            // position               // color
            0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,       1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // Bottom right 0
            -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,       0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // Top left     1
            0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f ,      1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // Top right    2
            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,       1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // Bottom left  3
    };

    //IMPORTANT: Must be in counter-clockwise order
    private int[] elementArray = {
            /*
                    x        x


                    x        x
             */
            2, 1, 0, // Top right triangle
            0, 1, 3 // bottom left triangle
    };

    private int vaoId, vboId, eboId;


    /*
     * Main Object
     */
    public DemoScene(Game game) {
        super(game, "DemoScene");
    }


    /*
     * Methods
     */
    public void init() {

        /*
         * Vertex
         */
        vertexId = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(vertexId, vertexShaderSrc);
        glCompileShader(vertexId);

        //Check for errors
        int success = glGetShaderi(vertexId, GL_COMPILE_STATUS);
        if (success == GL_FALSE) {
            int len = glGetShaderi(vertexId, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH);
            System.out.println("ERROR: 'defaultShader.glsl' - (vertex) compilation failed!");
            System.out.println(glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexId, len));
            assert false : "";
        }

        /*
         * Fragment
         */
        fragmentId = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        // Pass the shader source to the GPU
        glShaderSource(fragmentId, fragmentShaderSrc);
        glCompileShader(fragmentId);

        // Check for errors in compilation
        success = glGetShaderi(fragmentId, GL_COMPILE_STATUS);
        if (success == GL_FALSE) {
            int len = glGetShaderi(fragmentId, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH);
            System.out.println("ERROR: 'defaultShader.glsl'\n\tFragment shader compilation failed.");
            System.out.println(glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentId, len));
            assert false : "";
        }

        /*
         * Link shaders
         */
        shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
        glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexId);
        glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentId);
        glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);

        // Check for linking errors
        success = glGetProgrami(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS);
        if (success == GL_FALSE) {
            int len = glGetProgrami(shaderProgram, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH);
            System.out.println("ERROR: 'defaultShader.glsl'\n\tLinking of shaders failed.");
            System.out.println(glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, len));
            assert false : "";
        }

        // ============================================================
        // Generate VAO, VBO, and EBO buffer objects, and send to GPU
        // ============================================================
        vaoId = glGenVertexArrays();
        glBindVertexArray(vaoId);

        // Create a float buffer of vertices
        FloatBuffer vertexBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(vertexArray.length);
        vertexBuffer.put(vertexArray).flip();

        // Create VBO upload the vertex buffer
        vboId = glGenBuffers();
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        // Create the indices and upload
        IntBuffer elementBuffer = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(elementArray.length);
        elementBuffer.put(elementArray).flip();

        eboId = glGenBuffers();
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, eboId);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, elementBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        // Add the vertex attribute pointers
        int positionsSize = 3;
        int colorSize = 4;
        int floatSizeBytes = 4;
        int vertexSizeBytes = (positionsSize + colorSize) * floatSizeBytes;
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, positionsSize, GL_FLOAT, false, vertexSizeBytes, 0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

        glVertexAttribPointer(1, colorSize, GL_FLOAT, false, vertexSizeBytes, positionsSize * floatSizeBytes);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    }

    public void preload() {

    }

    public void create() {

    }

    //Update (looped)
    public void update(float delta) {

        System.out.println("" + (1.0f / delta) + "FPS");

        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
        // Bind the VAO that we're using
        glBindVertexArray(vaoId);

        // Enable the vertex attribute pointers
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, elementArray.length, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

        // Unbind everything
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);

        glBindVertexArray(0);

        glUseProgram(0);

    }

}
```

Here's the window program as well:

````
package org.hootengine.display;

import org.hootengine.core.Game;
import org.hootengine.input.KeyListener;
import org.hootengine.input.MouseListener;
import org.hootengine.time.TimeManager;
import org.lwjgl.Version;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallback;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GLUtil;
import org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.Callbacks.glfwFreeCallbacks;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;

/**
 * @author Patrick Carroll
 */
public class Window {

    /*
     * Variables
     */

    /**
     * The game object.
     */
    private Game game;

    /**
     * The window instance.
     */
    public static Window instance = null;

    /**
     * The window saved to memory.
     */
    private long glfwWindow;

    /**
     * The width (in pixels) of the window.
     */
    private int width;

    /**
     * The height (in pixels) of the window.
     */
    private int height;

    /**
     * The title of the window.
     */
    private String title;


    /*
     * Main Objects
     */

    /**
     * Sets the properties of a new game window.
     */
    private Window(Game game) {

        this.game = game;

        width = game.getConfig().getWidth();
        height = game.getConfig().getHeight();
        title = game.getConfig().getTitle();

    }


    /*
     * Methods
     */

    /**
     * Initializes the window and starts the refresh loop.
     */
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Window created using LWJGL version " + Version.getVersion() + "!");

        init();
        startLoop();

        //Free the memory
        glfwFreeCallbacks(glfwWindow);
        glfwDestroyWindow(glfwWindow);

        //Terminate GLFW and the free the error callback
        glfwTerminate();
        glfwSetErrorCallback(null).free();
    }

    /**
     * Creates a game window and sets the callbacks.
     */
    private void init() {

        GLFWErrorCallback.createPrint(System.err).set();

        if (!glfwInit()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to initialize GLFW.");
        }

        glfwDefaultWindowHints();
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW_FALSE);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_TRUE);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_DEBUG_CONTEXT, GL_TRUE);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 1);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
        //glfwWindowHint(GLFW_MAXIMIZED, GLFW_TRUE);

        //Create the window
        glfwWindow = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title, MemoryUtil.NULL, MemoryUtil.NULL);
        if (glfwWindow == MemoryUtil.NULL) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to create the GLFW window.");
        }

        //Set mouse callbacks
        glfwSetCursorPosCallback(glfwWindow, MouseListener::mousePosCallback);
        glfwSetMouseButtonCallback(glfwWindow, MouseListener::mouseButtonCallback);
        glfwSetScrollCallback(glfwWindow, MouseListener::mouseScrollCallback);

        //Set key callbacks
        glfwSetKeyCallback(glfwWindow, KeyListener::keyCallback);

        //Make the OpenGL context current
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(glfwWindow);
        //Enable v-sync
        glfwSwapInterval(1);

        //Show window
        glfwShowWindow(glfwWindow);

        //IMPORTANT!
        GL.createCapabilities();
        GLUtil.setupDebugMessageCallback();

        if (game.getSceneManager().getCurrentGameScene() != null)
            game.getSceneManager().getCurrentGameScene().start();

    }

    /**
     * Start the window refresh loop.
     */
    public void startLoop() {

        float beginTime = TimeManager.getTime();
        float endTime;
        float delta = -1.0f;

        while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(glfwWindow)) {
            //Poll events
            glfwPollEvents();

            glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            glfwSwapBuffers(glfwWindow);

            //Update the scenes
            if (delta >= 0)
                game.getSceneManager().update(delta);

            endTime = TimeManager.getTime();
            delta = endTime - beginTime;
            beginTime = endTime;

        }

    }


    /*
     * Getters & Setters
     */

    /**
     * @return The game window instance.
     */
    public static Window get(Game game) {

        if (Window.instance == null) {
            Window.instance = new Window(game);
        }

        return Window.instance;

    }

}
```
````